# why does my react header does not render at all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

So I have a a component called Header that will display a nav bar depending if a user is logged in or not, the props I am passing is a prop from the parent component that returns true as the user is already authenticated after login

**App**

```
 <Header IsLoggedIn={this.state.IsLoggedIn} />
```

then this is my Header component that is not rendering

**Header**

```
// stateless functional component
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'; //import Navlink to create nav links and to put active class on any link that is active
import UserGreeting from './UserGreeting'
import GuestGreeting from './GuestGreeting'
/*Header- Displays the top menu bar for the application and 
includes buttons for signing in and signing up 
(if there's not an authenticated user) or the user's first and last name 
and a button for signing out (if there's an authenticated user).*/


function Header(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props;
  console.log(props)
  if (isLoggedIn ===true) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  else if(isLoggedIn===false) {
    return <GuestGreeting />;
  }
}

export default Header;
```

this is the error I get when I reload the page:

*Uncaught Invariant Violation: Header(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.* Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

If `isLoggedIn` is `undefined` then `isLoggedIn === false` evaluates to `false` which causes your component to not return anything and results in the error you are seeing.

---

Change your `else` clause to this:

```
else {
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}
```

...or as @Isaac points out, remove the `else` completely and just do this:

```
if (isLoggedIn === true) {
  return <UserGreeting />;
}
return <GuestGreeting />;
```

...and that should fix it.

---

Ah, and @Jose is correct that you should use destructuring: `const { isLoggedIn } = props;`...that is **why** `isLoggedIn` was `undefined` in the first place.

Comment: Can even remove the replace the whole else block with only `return <GuestGreeting />`

Answer (score 1):

You should use es6 destructuring:

```js
const { isLoggedIn } = props;
```

If you don't destructure your props, you're not getting the correct value from `isLoggedIn` so you don't return anything (thus the error).

Also don't need to check if false, just do:

```js
function Header(props) {
  const { isLoggedIn } = props;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  } else {
    return <GuestGreeting />;
  }
}
```

---

> TIP: You can do something like this for keeping your code tidy

```js
const Header = ({ isLoggedIn }) => isLoggedIn ? <UserGreeting /> : <GuestGreeting />
```

Comment: So I decided to use this ```function Header(props) {
  const { isLoggedIn } = props;
  console.log(isLoggedIn) //this is undefined
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  } else {
    return <GuestGreeting />;
  }
}```

Comment: I am able to see the website now, I can still login, but the Header is not updating based on the user's login status, also when I do this console.log(isLoggedIn) //this is undefined, the isLoggedIn comes up as undefined

Comment: Probably because you're passing *IsLoggedIn* (capitalized) as props when it should be *isLoggedIn*. Props by convenience are in camelCase format.